# PHP self-emailing form doesn't work

Tags: php, html, email

So I've been trying to get a PHP script to send an email to myself when a page form is filled out. An example of the page is found here:
http://tonybenwhite.byethost8.com/WSAWebpage/Action.html
The hosting service DOES allow PHP, and my web dev instructor said the PHP looks correct, but the email won't send. Here's the PHP script and the HTML form:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        $to_address="my@email.com";
        $subject="WSA Day of Action Entry";
        $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $street1=$_POST['street1'];
        $street2=$_POST['street2'];
        $city=$_POST['city'];
        $state=$_POST['state'];
        $zip=$_POST['zip'];
        $initials=$_POST['initials'];
        $message="Name: " .$firstname." ".$lastname."\n";
        $message .="Email: " .$email."\n";
        $message .="Street: " .$street1."\n";
        $message .="Street: " .$street2."\n";
        $message .="City: " .$city."\n";
        $message .="State: " .$state."\n";
        $message .="Zip Code: " .$zip."\n";
        $message .="Initials: " .$initials."\n";
        $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' .phpversion();
        mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
?>


    <form name="infoForm" method="post" action="email.php">
        <fieldset class="formfield">
            <p class="form">
                Are you a registered voter in the state of Washington?<br>
                <input type="checkbox" id="yesBox"/> Yes<br><br>

                First Name: <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br>
                Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName"><br><br>

                Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="30"><br><br>
                Street Address: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="street1" name="street1" size="30"><br>
                <input type="text" id="street2" name="street2" size="30"><br>
                City: <input type="text" id="city" name="city" size="30"><br>
                State: <input type="text" id="state" name="state" size="30"><br>
                Zip Code: <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" size="30"><br><br>
                Initials: <input type="text" id="initials" name="initials" size="3"><br><br>

                <input type="submit" name="send" class="inputButton" id="send" value="Submit" disabled=true/> <input type="reset" name="resetFields" class="inputButton" id="reset" value="Reset"/><label id="disableLabel"> <i><font size="2px">Please confirm you are a WA State Voter!</font></i></label>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `my@email.com` your actual email? Just checking if you filled in that field.

Comment: Oh, yes it actually contains my email in my webpage, I just replaced it with that for privacy's sake

Comment: disabled=true in submit button !! Take that out.

Comment: @TonyWhite Okay, good. That could be a major trip-up.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty that is set to false when the checkmark is checked. It's part of an earlier bit of javascripting to make sure that whoever fills out the form confirms they're a washington registrated voter.

Comment: Are you **SURE** it "doesn't send"? Did you bother checking the return value of `mail()` for boolean false? Did you check the mail server's logs to see what happened after (if?) PHP handed over the email? Just because you didn't receive doesn't mean PHP screwed up. Email is a very complicated business and PHP is involved in only a microscopically small part of the whole process.

Comment: I'm basically in web dev 101, I don't know how to do any of that stuff :x

Comment: @MarcB I used the following code:
` if (mail($to_address, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  echo "Message successfully sent!";
 } else {
  echo "Message delivery failed...";
 }`
And it returns "Message Successfully Sent!". So I'm at a loss as to what the problem is that's making me not receive it.

Comment: so check your mail server's logs, then. once PHP returns from mail(), it's completely done with the process: but all you've done is the equivalent of walking your letter down to the mailbox on the corner and tossed it into the box. NOw you have to check the mail server logs (e.g. the post office) to see what happened to the letter once it entered the mailbox.

Comment: @MarcB I don't know how to check hotmail's server logs, but I'll google around for instruction

Comment: So you are sending from Hotmail's servers? Are you also sending from an address that Hotmail approves? Checked your spam box?

Comment: you're not using hotmail's servers. you're using your local php machine's mail server, which is where PHP is handing the email over to... unless you're on a windows box and pointed PHP at hotmail.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** The link you provided does have JS to work in conjunction with your submit button.

Disregard what was posted originally as strikethroughs, but continue reading passed that.

<strike>I don't know if this is your full and actual code, whether you have JS to check if all fields are filled, yet this `disabled=true` in:</strike>

```
<input type="submit" name="send" class="inputButton" id="send" value="Submit" disabled=true/>
```

<strike>The submit button will not be clickable since the submit is `disabled` / set to `true`.</strike>

This won't prevent mail from doing its job, however some of your form elements do not match your POST variables.

For instance:

```
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
```

along with `name="firstName"` and `name="lastName"`

those are case-sensitive, therefore they should be changed to `name="firstname"` and `name="lastname"` respectively.

Using the following in two seperate files was sent and received successfully. I'm wondering if you are using your entire code inside the same file.

If so, use `action=""` instead of `email.php` **IF** your file isn't named `email.php`

PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        $to_address="my@email.com";
        $subject="WSA Day of Action Entry";
        $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
        $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $street1=$_POST['street1'];
        $street2=$_POST['street2'];
        $city=$_POST['city'];
        $state=$_POST['state'];
        $zip=$_POST['zip'];
        $initials=$_POST['initials'];
        $message="Name: " .$firstname." ".$lastname."\n";
        $message .="Email: " .$email."\n";
        $message .="Street: " .$street1."\n";
        $message .="Street: " .$street2."\n";
        $message .="City: " .$city."\n";
        $message .="State: " .$state."\n";
        $message .="Zip Code: " .$zip."\n";
        $message .="Initials: " .$initials."\n";
        $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' .phpversion();
        mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
?>
```

HTML form:

```
<form name="infoForm" method="post" action="email.php">
    <fieldset class="formfield">
        <p class="form">
            Are you a registered voter in the state of Washington?<br>
            <input type="checkbox" id="yesBox"/> Yes<br><br>

            First Name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><br><br>

            Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="30"><br><br>
            Street Address: &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" id="street1" name="street1" size="30"><br>
            <input type="text" id="street2" name="street2" size="30"><br>
            City: <input type="text" id="city" name="city" size="30"><br>
            State: <input type="text" id="state" name="state" size="30"><br>
            Zip Code: <input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" size="30"><br><br>
            Initials: <input type="text" id="initials" name="initials" size="3"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" name="send" class="inputButton" id="send" value="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" name="resetFields" class="inputButton" id="reset" value="Reset"/>
            <label id="disableLabel"> <i><font size="2px">Please confirm you are a WA State Voter!</font></i></label>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```